# Can't send the mail using the nodemailer using oauth method

Tags: node.js, oauth, google-api, nodemailer

I can't send the email using oauth.

So I am authenticating user to send the gmail using their gmail account. I have created the web client in the google cloud console. I can send the email if I get the refresh token and access token from the oauth playground but can't using the `oauth2client.getToken(code)`.

this is my code:

```
const clientId = client.web.client_id
const clientSecret = client.web.client_secret
const REDIRECT_URI = 'https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground'
const oauth2client = new google.auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, 'postmessage')
exports.sendGmail = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const code = req.body
        console.log(code)
        const tokens = await oauth2client.getToken(code)
        console.log(tokens)
        oauth2client.setCredentials({
            refresh_token: tokens.tokens.refresh_token
        })

        const access_token = tokens.tokens.access_token
        console.log(access_token)
        const refresh_token = tokens.tokens.refresh_token
        console.log(refresh_token)
        console.log(clientId)
        console.log(clientSecret)
        const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
                type: 'OAuth2',
                user: 'authenticated email account',
                clientId: clientId,
                clientSecret: clientSecret,
                refreshToken: refresh_token,
                accessToken: access_token
            }
        })
        console.log(transport)
        const mailOptions = {
            from: 'Name <email account>',
            to: 'email account',
            subject: 'Hello from gmail using API',
            text: 'Hello from gmail email using API',
            html: '<h1>Hello from gmail email using API</h1>'
        }

        transport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
            } else {
                console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response)
            }
        })
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'done' })
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
}
```

if you need any other info feel free to ask.

Comment: Why not just use the Gmail api?